# how to delete a customer from back end-zen cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, zen-cart

I like to know is there any way to delete a customer from back end side in zen cart.

I all ways delete a customer details from data base manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to admin site click customers tab in the menu

and then whatever you want to delete or edit.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I checked it but there is no edit, delete button to click on

Comment: look at right side there are some buttons such as edit delete email.as screen shot says..

Comment: sure you going in right direction? admin site than customer tab?

Comment: Jack I'm in the right page in the back end there. IN the navigation bar I mouse overred the fourth option "Customers" and clicked first option "Customers"

Comment: In that page I can see customers details but there is no edit or delete button to click

Comment: yes your going right select a customer,than look at the right side as mentioned in Screen shot, i dont know why its not coming can you post image what's coming at your end?

Comment: How can I post the image, I'm new to this site.

Comment: I tried to post a image but I require more then 10 reputation to post an image currently i have only 5

Comment: post it anywhere on the web and give me the link I'll short it out

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/705/test1u.png/

Comment: Are you able to visit the image Jack?

Comment: yes i am on it will get back to u soon

Comment: i guess your side box is hidden, please ensure. check your configuration

Comment: Just copy in a NEW copy of the general.php into admin/includes/functions and keep the old one renamed if new one does not work rollback to the old one try this

Comment: Jack i got the options to edit and delete option and the functionalities are working properly. Thanks man.

Comment: Is there any thing that I can do to vote for you or some thing.

Comment: @raj you can vote me now

Comment: bs bhai dua kar mere liye..in vote se kuch nai hona :)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this video helps: http://www.blogadr.com/tutorials/free-zen-cart-tutorial/zencart_admin_customers.html
According to the video there should be a section that allows you manage customers in the admin side.

Comment: Sorry if the link didn't work, but it looks like you got the answer you wanted. The link should work now, but Pradeep has pretty much covered it.

Comment: Yes Nine, any ways thanks for offering your help. much appreciated. :)